# AS3 getting vars, but can't access

Tags: php, actionscript-3

I am trying to get some user data from PHP to AS3.

When I execute my code in AS3 I get this: `&levelUser=5&livesUser=5` And its good, it's all the data I want to transfer

But when I try to get only one variable I get this error:

```
ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property livesUser not found on String and there is no default value.
at petRush_fla::MainTimeline/serverResponse()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()
```

And I don't know who this is happening, I left my code here:

```
    function conectToServer() {
    //Conectamos al servidor
    loadingNum.text = "Connection to server...";

    var zahtjev:URLRequest=new URLRequest("getUserInfo.php");
    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, serverResponse);
    loader.load(zahtjev);

}

var livesVar:String;

function serverResponse(e:Event):void {
    trace(e.target.data.livesUser);
    gotoAndStop(2);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data returned is a string, and you need to create a URLVariables instance like this :

```
function serverResponse(e:Event):void {
    var myVariables:URLVariables = new URLVariables(e.target.data);
    trace(myVariables.livesUser);
    gotoAndStop(2);
}
```

Also I should note that your string shouldn't begin with a `&`, it should be :

`levelUser=5&livesUser=5`